# Displaying headers and rows from a base class MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a base class that a number of classes inherit from. Each derived class has a partial view inclusing the base class. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(item => ((Inq_DetailsBase)Model))
```

To display all the headers and values from the base class. However i get a

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

I understand that I need to then type out the member names for that base class. However, this seems to defeat the purpose of re-usability. Is there a way in my partial views to display the members in my base class without having to type each of them out?

Comment: Use `Html.Partial()` instead of `Html.DisplayFor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't just put the Base into it's own Partial? Something similar to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257355/mvc3-passing-base-class-to-partial-view-submitting-form-only-has-parent-class).

View (~/Views/Home/Inq_Details.cshtml):

```
@model Inq_Details
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Partial("Inq_DetailsBase", Model)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DetailsField1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DetailsField2)
    ....
}
```

Partial (~/Views/Home/Inq_DetailsBase.cshtml):

```
@model Inq_DetailsBase
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BaseField1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BaseField2)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BaseField3)
```

Then you just need to change the Detail pages and the Base will sta